# Panel width not fitting the whole space

Tags: extjs

Hello i am defining a Panel like so :

```
    Ext.define('Mine.view.newDashboardPanel', {
        extend: 'Ext.Container',
        xtype: 'basic-panels',
        requires: [
            'Ext.layout.container.Table'
        ],
    
        width: 760,
        height: 500,
        layout: 'fit',
    
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'panel',
            width: 1240,
            height: 600,
            padding: 0
        },
    
        items: [{
            title: 'proj'
    
        
});
```

But the `default` property fields `width` and `height` set to 100% don't stretch the panel. For now i am setting it at `1140 px` which i don't want.

How to achieve that ?

Thanks

EDIT : Is it possible to style the Panel to stretch it on the whole screen ?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Usually `layout: 'fit'` should do the trick.
You do not need to set height or width.
I tried it in a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/39ei) and it works fine.

As you are setting `defaults`, I guess you want to add several panels.
If you use `fit` this layout might not work as you want.

- underneath each other. Use the `vbox` layout.
- next to each other. User the `hbox` layout.

Both layout support `align`, which in your case sould be `stretch`.

Here an example:

```
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'stretch'
},
```